# Defining separate tables or joining them into one table and have null values

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I want to manage the relationship between ((Permision_Role ... Group .. users)). And a permission_role can be associated with single users or a group of users or both of them.

**I have two way of managing this.

**Either to have three tables without having to deal with nulls:-**

[image]

**Or to have two tables and allow null values:-**

[image]

So which approach i should follow and why?

Comment: Could both FKs in PermissionRoleDetails be NULL ?

Comment: yes FK will allow null values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization wise, you're supposed to have a value for every columns. Since NULL isn't a value, you should do your best to avoid it.

However this is arguable in your case. As you pointed out, it's not semantically incorrect that a permission could be linked to either a group, a user, both or none. NULL fits for these columns : either you have it or you don't. Therefore avoiding the joins and their overhead by denormalizing a bit doesn't seem unreasonable to me.

Now if PermissionRoleDetails isn't gonna be some huge table, the first option may be more suitable. Your call.

Comment: thanks for your reply. so you mean it is better to have two tables ?

Comment: @JohnPeter Better would imply there is some kind of rule, but there isn't. It's just an understandable alternative.

Comment: so both approaches are valid ,, from Database architecture point of view?

Comment: @JohnPeter Quick edit. Theoretically, rules are saying you should take first option. I'm saying that depending on the number of records I may go for option two (for the reasons I said above)